# Header full width in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am stuck trying to get the header full width in the woocommerce pages of my website.In every other page its full width.There is an element style that gives width 90% and i cant seem to find how to change it.Anyone any ideas?Thanks

codes i used

```
#top-classic.header-style2.top.header-light.logo-dark{
max-width:100% !important;
}

.content.top.style-wireframe{
max-width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: header.header-light .navigation-button, header.header-light .mobile-sidebar, header.header-light .mobile-shopcart, header.header-light{maxwidth:100%}

Comment: above many other css i have tried

Comment: ehm why would i do that?

Comment: I have tried various codes one of them is written so people can see it.If someone has any idea please let me know